# google console error You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate

Tags: android, android-studio, signed, google-console-developer

6 months ago my app got suspended on google console now i have edit it and trying to release it as a new or a different (with a new signed certificate i lost the old one) app but when i try to add my APK on google console i got error

`You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint:
[ SHA1: FD:90:0F:B2:C6:8D:CD:21:43:8F:19:10:D6:4E:7E:14:4C:DD:A0:EA ]
and the certificate used to sign the APK that you uploaded have fingerprint:
[ SHA1: 14:A0:7F:6A:D5:36:59:3F:67:4B:F2:E6:5D:D9:E7:49:9B:58:C2:04 ]`

and i cant delete my suspended app at all

p.s i have changed the package name and still have the same error.

Comment: You need the old certificate to be able to upload the app.

Comment: that does not make sense

Comment: is that mean i cant uplode any app without my old cerificate?

Comment: There's a certificate stored on their servers, and that's the one you habe to use.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation on App signing keys is here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423)

The fact it is saying your upload key doesn't match suggests your app is using Google Play App Signing. There is a section at the bottom of that page called "*Create a new upload key*". If you have lost the old key you will have to follow the steps in that section. Specifically:

- Step 1: Generate a new private key and upload certificate
- Step 2: Contact the Google Play support team

PS. Saying "I changed the package name and still have the same error" doesn't make any sense. There is no knowledge shared between apps with different package names. And you can't change the package name for an existing app - you would have to create it again as a new app. You can't just change the package name in an apk.